# How many rods to purchase?

Tags: linear-programming, discrete-optimization

Available rods lengths in the shop = 144 inches and 180 inches.

Question: How many rods do I need to purchase if my requirement is as below?

70 inches each -> 3 rods

45 inches each -> 2 rods

The choice of length of the rod to purchase could be either 144 or 180 inches and they both are of the same price per inch/foot. The goal is the make less wastage possible.

With Brute force, I came up with this. (Note: I have simplified the question for lesser requirements)
[image]

Comment: This appears to be a homework problem (and tagging it linear-algebra is a bit of a stretch), so show us how far you've gotten on your own.

Comment: No, it's not homework, I have to purchase the rods tomorrow. I have tried to do it manually. There are a lot of types of rods for my problem and I am looking for a formula. I am not sure under what tag the question goes in also.

Comment: This can be modeled as a linear-programming exercise.  And there are standard methods to solve these sorts of problems.  e.g. the simplex method.  However the number of combinations of long rods and short rods is fairly small, and we can brute force through the cases.

Comment: Thanks I am looking into the simple method.

Comment: You need 3*70+2*45 = 300" of rods.  The most efficient way to buy 300" is to buy one long one and one short one, wasting 24".   So, can you cut those two rods in such a way as to fulfill your needs?  Sure, cut the short rod into two 70" lengths and the long rod into lengths of 70, 45, 45.

Comment: simplex* not simple.
@DougM - Please check my question. I have added the manual calculation. I was looking for one time formulae for ever changing requirement. Manual is time consuming, we all know that.

Comment: @Ashwin: There is always two types of rods that you can buy and there is up to two types of rods that you need to produce by cutting. Is it correct? Type means length.

Comment: @Ashwin: I think I see what you're getting at, but it would be clearer if you put your request for a general algorithm explicitly in the original post, rather than only in the comments here.

Comment: There is one more solution for 33×20 case which is as good as found.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu - Each color corresponds to separate type of rod and each rod are available in 2 lengths (144 & 180)

Comment: @Ashwin: You need to get solution only for requirements shown in picture or you need to get solution for more general case? If you need to get solution for more general case then you should write exactly what is common for all cases. I believe one common fact is that you always can buy only 144 or 180 (any number of these). Other possible common fact is that your requirement contains not more than two lengths. If your requirement may contain any number of lengths, I believe there cannot be general formula, only algorithm.

Comment: @Ashwin What is your question? Have you set up a linear optimization problem and solved it? If yes, then it seems the right way.

Comment: Your first two instances (red and green) are identical.

Comment: @RobPratt - Each color represents different rod. i.e. red rod of length 180 inches can be cut only for red (70 x3, 45 x 2) and not for green (70 x3, 45 x 2). So, I am looking for a solution only for one of the color, rest I suppose can be calculated likewise.
Anyways fellas ! Today I go and buy the rods as per the excel screenshot in the question. Thanks all of you!

Comment: OK, did you see my 0 waste solution for the last color?

Comment: Yes, and I have accepted the change. This saved me 72 inches of wastage. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *multiple length cutting stock problem*.  Via integer linear programming, I confirmed optimality of all but the last of your solutions.  The last one can actually be satisfied with 0 waste by taking 6 of the 144" rods, each covering 3 of the 34" and 2 of the 21" demands.

Comment: Downvote within 1 minute?  What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: It looks like a nice answer to me, so I've upvoted it.  The only thing I think of that might be worth adding is to show how the problem can be formulated as an integer linear program  and how one could get hold of a good integer programming package to solve it..

Comment: @RobPratt - I Agree. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Brute force. Below is *every* sensible possibility

A) How much pipe do we need?  $3\times 70 + 2\times 45 = 300$.

B) How many ways are there to get $300$ inches of pipes (regardless if we can saw them to the length we want) from all long to all short.

1. $2\times 180 = 360; 60$ wastage
2. $180 + 144 = 324; 24$ wastage
3. $2\times 144 =288$ failure
4. $3\times 144 = 432; 132$ wastage

If possible we want to do $2$ as that is the least wastage if the cuts are possible.

C) Is it possible cut these ways.  Big to small.

2--- we have $180$ and $144$.  Try to get as many of the $70$ from the $180$ if possible.

$70+70=140;40$ left over.  That's $40$ that can't be used by either $70$ or $45$ so that's $40$ inches of wastage when we only had $24$ to spare.  Can't do it this way.

So we can do it at all we must take at least $2$ of the $70$ from the $144$.  That gives us $70+70=140; 4$ left over.  That's $4$ inches of wastage from rod and all the rest (one $70$ and the two $45$) must come from the $180$ pipe.  As $70 + 2\times 45 = 160$ we have the expected $20$ inches of wastage.

Now we must take at least two of the $70$ from the $144$ and we can't take anything *else* from the $144$ so the is the only way to do option $2$.

So we know this is the best option and we don't have to look any further.

....

but lets do it for practice.

1--- we have two $180$.  Try to be as many of the $70$s from one of the $180$.  $2\times 70 = 140$ and that leaves $40$ for that pipe that is good for nothing.  So we can't have all three $70$ from one the $180$ so we must at least one of the $70$ from one pipe.  That means each rod must have at least one $70$.  That means one rod with have one $70$ and the other will have two $70$s.  That we leave $40$ wastage from one rod, and we will have $110$ from the other. That's enough for $2\times 45$ with $20$ wastage.

So we can do $70+70$ with $40$ wastage from one pipe and $70+2\times 45$ with $20$ wastage on the other.  That is the only way to do option 1.

3--- we have $3$ $144$ pipes.

They are all the same rod so we must take a $70$ from one of them.  We can only take a maximum of two $70$s from one of them so we must take $70$ from two of them.  That will leave us with two $74$ inch remaining rods and one untouched $144$ rod, for the remaining $70$ inches and the two $45$.

We can a) take the remaining $70$ from one of the two $74$ rods, or b) take the remaining $70$ from the $144$ rod.

If we do a) we will have $4$ inches of wastage of one rod, one $74$ inch rod, and an untouched $144$ to get two $45s$.   we can't get both $45$ from the $74$ inch rod so we must get one $45$ from the $144$ and have a $99$ inch rod remaining.

So we a $74$ inch rod, and a $99$ inch rod to get one remaining $45$ inch cut.  We can take it from either pipe.

If we do b)  we have three $74$ inch rods for two $45$ inch cuts.  We have to take them from two different rods.

So there are three different ways to do 4----

4a) From 1 $144$ pipe take $2\times 70$.  From a second $144$ pipe take $70$ and $45$. and take $45$ from the third.

4b) From 1 $144$ pipe take $2\times 70$.  From the second take $70$ and from the third take $2\times 45$.

4c) From two of them take $70 + 45$ and from the third take $45$.

But all of those are the least efficient and have $132$ nearly an entire rod of wastage.